# cómo integrar stripe webhook con strapi

Tags: stripe, webhook, strapi

Estoy haciendo una integración de stripe con strapi y no he dado con la solución, como debo configurar mi middleware en strapi para obtener el cuerpo de la solicitud de webhook de stripe sin procesar, pero solo para la ruta del webhook sin afectar las otras rutas.

He tratado con esto en mi middleware.js

```
   module.exports = [
  'strapi::errors',
  'strapi::security',
  'strapi::cors',
  'strapi::poweredBy',
  'strapi::logger',
  'strapi::query',
  {
    name: "strapi::body",
    config: {
      includeUnparsed: true,
    },
  },
  'strapi::session',
  'strapi::favicon',
  'strapi::public',
];
```

pero si sigue dando errores asi:

> Error: No webhook payload was provided.
> at parseEventDetails (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:78:19)
> at Object.verifyHeader (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:58:102)
> at Object.constructEvent (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:11:28)
> at Object.webhookstripe (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/src/api/stripe/controllers/stripe.js:179:40)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at returnBodyMiddleware (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:52:24)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at policiesMiddleware (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/policy.js:24:11)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at /home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:33:12
> undefined [2023-07-18 23:30:58.609] error: No webhook payload was
> provided. Error: No webhook payload was provided.
> at parseEventDetails (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:78:19)
> at Object.verifyHeader (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:58:102)
> at Object.constructEvent (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/stripe/cjs/Webhooks.js:11:28)
> at Object.webhookstripe (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/src/api/stripe/controllers/stripe.js:179:40)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at returnBodyMiddleware (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:52:24)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at policiesMiddleware (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/policy.js:24:11)
> at dispatch (/home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/koa-compose/index.js:42:32)
> at /home/gabo/Documentos/strapi/rty_back/node_modules/@strapi/strapi/lib/services/server/compose-endpoint.js:33:12